# Cannot scroll page using keyboard in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have found a very strange problem in one of the site I have been working on, the issue is regarding scrolling the page from up/down using keyboard in chrome, this is the structure I have ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wqL6t7he/))

In this page what I have changed is, reset the body scroll by doing `overflow:hidden` of html and body and enabled the scroll in container.

This problem is showing, when you open the site in chrome and do not click anywhere in the page, just try scrolling using keyboard down arrow, however this works fine when you click anywhere on the page. And this problem is only showing in chrome for now.

How do I get this fixed? keeping in mind the same structure (without enabling overflow in html/body)

Please help!!

```css
html, body {
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
  <p>Hello this is test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a tabindex to the div :

```
<div class="wrapper" tabindex="1">...
```

then add this script :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")[0].focus();
```

Comment: that alot mate, you saved my life..I have been struggling with it for more than 8 hrs...thanks alot!!

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) recommends to only use a tabindex of 0 or -1, but it does still work well with 0.